# What is "Oki-doki" or "Oki-dokie" or "Okay-dokay"

Tags: orthography, history

Okay, since now we know what is the origin of [OK](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25617/difference-between-ok-and-okay) (I like the Oll Korrect version), I have another question about it's relative:

What is an "Oki-doki" or "Oki-dokie" or "Okay-dokay"?
What is the correct spelling? Where did it come from?

Comment: It's [rhyming reduplication](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79747/source-of-bie-in-freebie) and the usual spelling is *okey-dokey* (see the accepted answer in that question).

Comment: nice, why then it has been changed to okEy?

Comment: For the same reason you suggested *Oki-doki* -- it's easier to say than *okay-dokay*. Changing one letter from *okay* to *okey* keeps a resemblance with the original -- if ever it should need to be written down, which isn't often.

Comment: It just means Okay or an acknowledgement of agreement

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's [rhyming reduplication](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79747/source-of-bie-in-freebie) and the usual spelling is okey-dokey (see the accepted answer in that question). – [Andrew Leach](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18696/andrew-leach)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a moot question, really. The etymology of the term is disputed, however, current usage is invariably synonymous with the adjective 'alright'.

I recommend using 'alright', 'satisfactory' or another 'grown-up' equivalent in formal or academic settings, 'okay' in informal or dubious communicative spheres, and owt you fucking like in those circles where you can get away with it.

Okie-diddle-dokie?

Comment: Never take advice from someone recommending the use of "alright."

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, when I was a child growing up in my homestate of Louisiana, there was a man running for the position of governor.  He went by his initials, which were O.K. Allen.  Somehow, people started spelling his name, "Okay." and over the years it stuck.  "Okay Dokay" is just the slang way.

Comment: Have you a reference for this?