# Gentle scratching

Tags: single-word-requests

My wife uses her nails to “gently scratch” our 3-year-old son’s back for ~15 mins right before falling sleep. He likes it a lot. There’s a word *škrabkať*  in my native language (Slovak), and I was wondering if there is a similar one in English. Do we *scratch* our children? Doesn’t it sound weird?

Comment: I tried to come up with an alternate word, but without much success. I considered [_caress_](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/caress), but that seems as likely to be misinterpreted as _scratch_; I think I prefer "gentle scratch" over "caress" – even more than "caress with the fingertips." By the way, even though _scratch_, by itself, usually has a somewhat rough connotation in English, that's not so much the case when you talk about scratching on the _back_. In fact, the idiom _you scratch my back, I'll scratch yours_ refers to two people helping either other out.

Comment: I concur with J.R.: "she scratched his back" evokes pretty much what you are describing without any further context. "She scratched his face" would need further context to be sure, but one would expect this to be violent. Perhaps because the back is an inconvenient place for the individual to reach himself (?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn’t official, but the verb ***scritch*** is sometimes used to mean a light, perhaps even a friendly, *scratching*, as if responding to an *itch*.  Think of it as a combination of *scratch + itch = scritch*.

Considering that the old meaning of *scritch* as a synonym for *screech* or *shriek* is now considered archaic, this neologism seems to fill an ecological niche in the language.  This use is reasonably well known, enough so as to find its way into the crowd-sourced [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=scritch).

The prior use of *scritch* as shriek goes back all the way to the 12<sup>th</sup> century, extending through the 20<sup>th</sup>.  Here are the OED’s first and last two citations:

> - A. 1250 *Owl & N.* 223 (Jesus MS.) ― Þu scrichest & yollest to þine fere, Þat hit is gryslich to ihere.
> - 13·· *Seuyn Sag.* (W.) 1290 ― Loude he gan to crie and skriche [*rime* diche].
> - 1944 W. de la Mare *Coll. Rhymes & Verses* 70 ― Down to the shore skipped Lallerie, His parrot on his thumb, And the twain they scritched in mockery.
> - 1957 H. Nicolson *Journey to Java* v. 88 ― The evening breeze stirs the tree above us and we hear the keel birds scritching.

I think using *scritch* for the sort of thing you asked about is pretty normal today.  As mentioned below in comments, [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scritch) mentions that *scritch* can mean “to scratch an itch”.  There also appear to be counter-cultural usages with which I was not previously familiar (and am still largely unclear on). [This online source, the “Cat Dictionary”](http://www.obliquity.com/cats/diction4.html), offers as an example:

> The cat has an itch and is scritching it.

Miriam Moss has an amusing children’s book named [*Scritch Scratch*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0439368359), which is about head lice, of all ***scritchy-scratchy*** things!  The Amazon description is:

> Miriam Moss and Delphine Durand tackle the uncomfortable issue of head lice in this straightforward and very silly picture book. Miss Calypso and her class become the unsuspecting hosts of a family of those pesky parasites, but fortunately, the principal knows how to handle them. In a surprise, romantic ending, the head lice end up being one of the best things to ever happen to Miss Calypso.

The use of *Scritch Scratch*, or of *scritchy-scratch(y)*, seems to follow the rule for reduplicative freezes that John Lawler mentions in his answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80547/crisscross-dillydally-riffraff-etc?lq=1).  Whether this is the ultimate source of the contemporary slang use of *scritch* as related to *scratch* is hard to pin down for certain, though.  It might also be one of those portmanteaux that show up so often, so *scratch + itch = scritch*.  Or as often happens in these cases, it could simply be several things working together to converge on a reinforced sense.

Comment: +1 Also has an entry in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scritch).

Comment: Hm, the word "scritch" isn't in LDOCE nor in The Oxford Dictionary that came with my iPhone. Is it used in everyday life? Do parents scritch their children?

Comment: Anecdotal, but on multiple occasions I got a request to give a *scritchy-scratch* to a friend's back. I declined, of course, because the word wasn't in the OED. (:

Comment: Take care with how you use "scritch" as well. In context its meaning would be clear, but the term also has a pretty strong (in popular usage on the internet at least) connection to furry culture.

Comment: @tchrist I'd link it but I still haven't figured out the proper format for that in a comment. It's people who dress and behave as anthropomorphic animals and is frequently sexual in nature.

Comment: @Zairja LOL! :D

Answer (score 2):

My children used to say

> *Itch me!*

See transitive verb, definition 2 [here](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/itch)