# Is there a name for this kind of phrases?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, vocabulary

I often times heard phrases like itty-bitty, nitty-gritty etc, the latter word followed part of the previous word's syllable(mostly ends with -y), I want to know the names for this kinds of phrases.

Comment: Wishy-washy though the answer might seem, these sorts of sing-song sayings are [frozen reduplicative phrases](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80551), and they often follow a very interesting pattern in lieu of rhyming.

Comment: Other familiar examples of ***rhyming reduplication*** include: *airy-fairy, cherry-merry, easy-peasy, flibberty-gibberty, fuddy-duddy, fuzzy-wuzzy, hanky-panky, higgledy-piggledy, highty-tighty, hoity-toity, hokey-pokey, hotsy-totsy, hurdy-gurdy, jelly-belly, lardy-dardy, lilly-pilly, lovey-dovey, namby-pamby, nilly-willy, party-hearty, Piggly-Wiggly, randy-dandy, teensy-weensy, willy-nilly,* and *wishy-washy.*

Comment: *flibberty-gibberty, hotsy-totsy, lilly-pilly* and *party-hearty* I have never heard of. Although I can guess the *party-hearty* meaning, "having a swell time", I'm at a loss for the previous ones.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Very pre-war: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flibberty-gibberty%2Chotsy-totsy%2Clilly-pilly&year_start=1870&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @tchrist: I don't know if you watch _The Simpsons_, but Ned Flanders is a master of rhyming reduplication.