# Knick-knack and bric-a-brac?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

There are several interesting words to describe the same idea:

**Knick-Knack** *and* **Bric-a-Brac**, both defined as:

> Small, decorative object(s) of little value.

[Bric-a-Brac](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bric-a-brac) derives from French and is Uncountable. [Knick-Knack](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/knick-knack) is Countable. Apart from these differences, I can’t see why there are different words. Perhaps different classes or regions use different words?

In addition, we have [**gewgaw**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gewgaw) and [**doodad**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doodad).

In some languages different phonemes can carry emotional significance.

For example, in local Spanish the same idea can be expressed as *cachibache*. The /tʃ/ can carry the idea of worthlessness.

Other Spanish examples with /tʃ/:

> *chuchería*-junk, junk food
>
> *chunche*-a piece of unidentifiable junk
>
> *casucha*-a shack or crappy house
>
> *pueblucho*-a one-horse town

In Korean, the usage of the /f/ sound used to be heard as immodest*

> *piksali* pault-fault confusion
>
> *bijinisu fureynduli* -business friendly

(sorry, can't reproduce Hangul here.)

Do repetitive syllables have any emotional significance?

**[EDIT]**
Thanks to the many wonderful and helpful comments which have been posted I am going to rework this question to express my original intent. Initially what I was thinking had to do with emotional content, but I don't think I expressed it very well.

After investigating further in Psycho-Linguistic topics I realize there *is* emotional content to F1-F2 and F2-F1 placement, and that individual phonemes *can* carry emotional significance. However, I need to collate this new information in order to reformulate my original idea into a more cogent and cohesive argument.

*"Huffing and Puffing about /f/ing everything" -Hyojin Cho Kim

Comment: Other options meaning much the same thing are the duplicate-syllable _gewgaw_, the k-kissed _trinket_, and the neither-of-the-above _bibelot_, _bauble_, and _curio_.

Comment: @SvenYargs You think maybe the repeated syllables are more significant?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the following question may be relevant to the vowel sounds and repetitive structure: [crisscross, dillydally, riffraff, etc](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80547/crisscross-dillydally-riffraff-etc)

Comment: Both words are also used in American English. I don't really understand your "objection" as to why both words exist: they came into English 3 centuries apart. And there are plenty of [synonyms](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english-thesaurus/bric-a-brac) that have nothing to do with /æk/, which sound  seems to me coincidental to the two words you ask about.

Comment: Having three such words meaning roughly the same thing is a striking coincidence, but I don't have any suggestions as to what significance the constructions might have. Actually, _doodads_ would be a fourth synonym containing almost-repeat syllables; and _Roget's Thesaurus_ suggests a fifth (that I've never heard of): _whim-wham_. Maybe there is a pidgin element in the repetitions that is more likely to occur in connection with "inexpensive trifles potentially offered in trade" than in other groups of synonyms.

Comment: I so nearly upvoted for the fascinating 'In some languages different phonemes can carry emotional significance....' But I'd complain if others did.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Should I delete the post and unclutter the site?

Comment: (Those words are English, not particularly British English.)

Comment: Maybe it's simpler than the vowel analysis. The *a* in *bric-a-brac* sounds like a colloquial version of *of*. Using *piece of paper* as a more familiar template, the plural would look like *brics-a-brac*, except that it sounds even more foreign, especially since *bric* and *brac* aren't in common usage as individual English words. This leaves the pluralisation *bric-a-bracs* (which already has a [dictionary entry at Memidex](http://www.memidex.com/bric-a-bracs)), or continued treatment as a mass noun. *Knick-knacks* is less complicated (no *of*), so can form plurals with the usual 'add -s'.

Comment: There is a good question (or probably two) behind this, though I'm not sure  that there would be anything beyond general reference. But asking 'Why does English have two words for ...?' rather than for etymologies or different nuances is almost certainly going to be off-topic.

Comment: My dad's favorite expression for a small, odd mechanism was "dingbob for a dodaddle".

Answer (score 2):

They are called ***[reduplications](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/reduplication.html)***:

> - The coinage of new words and phrases into English has been greatly enhanced by the pleasure we get from playing with words. There are numerous alliterative and rhyming idioms, which are a significant feature of the language. These aren't restricted to poets and Cockneys; everyone uses them. We start in the nursery with choo-choos, move on in adult life to hanky-panky and end up in the nursing home having a sing-song.
> - ***The repeating of parts of words to make new forms is called reduplication.*** There are various categories of this: rhyming, exact and ablaut (vowel substitution).
>
>   - Examples, are respectively, okey-dokey, wee-wee and zig-zag. The impetus for the coining of these seems to be nothing more than the enjoyment of wordplay. ***The words that make up these reduplicated idioms often have little meaning in themselves and only appear as part of a pair. In other cases, one word will allude to some existing meaning and the other half of the pair is added for effect or emphasis.***

Origin of ***knick-knack:***

> - ***Knick doesn't mean anything in itself in this term; it is merely a reduplication of knack.***  We now use knack as meaning 'a dexterous facility', but in the 16th century it was used to mean 'an ingenious contrivance; a toy or trinket', and that's the sense that was used in knick-knack.term;
> - Shakespeare also used it in The Taming of the Shrew, 1596:
>
>   - *"Why 'tis a cockle or a walnut-shell, A knacke, a toy, a tricke, a babies cap: Away with it."*
> - ***When knick-knack was first used it meant 'a petty trick or subtefuge'***. John Fletcher, used it that was in his work The loyall subject, 1618:
>
>   - *"If you use these knick-knacks, This fast and loose. "*
> - By 1682, that meaning had died out though and a translation of Nicolas Boileau-Despréaux's Le Lutrin was using the term with the meaning we currently have for it, that is, small trincket:
>
>   - *"Miss won't come in to Buy, before She spies the Knick-knacks at the Dore"*.

(The Phrase Finder)

Answer (score 0):

I'll point out that **bric-a-brac** is a collective noun, while **knick-knack** is a singular noun.

As such, at least in my view, **bric-a-brac** is less likely  to be use to refer to a specific item or items.

> I found this neat little **knick-knack** at the garage sale.
>
> I found these neat **knick-knacks** at the garage sale.

In my opinion it sounds a bit clumsy to say:

> I found some awesome **bric-a-brac** at the garage sale.
>
> I found this awesome piece of **bric-a-brac** at the garage sale.

However you might say:

> She loves collecting **bric-a-brac**.
>
> There was a lot of **bric-a-brac** at the garage sale.

Comment: Isn't that information in the question already? "Bric-a-Brac derives from French and is Uncountable. Knick-Knack is Countable. Apart from these differences, I can’t see why there are different words."

Comment: @sumelic you're right. I've edited my question, it might add some value.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a *knick-knack* is an individual object, such as a small statuette on a mantel, while *bric-a-brac* is a collection of decorative pieces attached to or surrounding a larger piece (such as *bric-a-brac* set into the edge of the mantel).

Thus a house may be described as having *bric-a-brac* accenting the gable.  *Knick-knacks* would never be described as accenting something in this fashion.

Though some people may use *bric-a-brac* to mean a simple collection/accumulation of *knick-knacks*, without the pieces being attached to anything.