# Looking for a name of this grammatical feature where (for example) "laptop" becomes "shmaptop"

Tags: grammar

I'm looking for a name of a below grammatical feature in writing. I googled a lot and I can't find it.

I think the name of this is something 'reverse', but not sure. Can someone help?

Spelling is most probably wrong.

> laptop - shmaptop
>
> car - shmar
>
> python - shmython
>
> belfast -  shmelfast

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Josephine, Schmosephine"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/379805/josephine-schmosephine): 'It is a type of productive reduplication forming a Yiddish “despective”, also known as shm-reduplication. (sometimes schm)' according to @Cascabel there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Shm-reduplication - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication)

> Shm-reduplication is a form of reduplication in which the original word or its first syllable (the base) is repeated with the copy (the reduplicant) beginning with shm- (sometimes schm-), pronounced /ʃm/. The construction is generally used to indicate irony, sarcasm, derision, skepticism, or lack of interest with respect to comments about the discussed object
>
> …
>
> The construction originated in Yiddish and was subsequently transferred to English, especially urban northeastern American English, by Yiddish-speaking Jewish immigrations from Central and Eastern Europe. It is now known and used by many non-Jewish English speakers, particularly American English.

The most famous example of dismissive usage is the saying:

> Cancer, shmancer, abi gezunt!

which mean something like "Cancer, who cares, as long as she's healthy!"

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.