# Is "helter skelter" a word or two words or two non-words? What do we call it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, terminology, freezes

The phrase "helter skelter" is strange because you don't see the word "helter" or "skelter" used anywhere, and when I searched Merriam-Webster dictionary for either word it links me to the definition of "helter skelter."

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/helter-skelter

Since helter and skelter are separated by either a space or a hyphen whenever it's used, it seems like a "compound word," but compound words are made up of other words, whereas "helter skelter" is made up of two "non-words" (for lack of a better word (so far)).

What do we call this?  Is there a term for a word like "helter" that is only a word when it's paired with another, "skelter?"

Comment: What's a "word"? Nobody has ever answered that. Calling it a contiguous stretch of alphabetics doesn’t work.

Comment: Jeepers creepers tchrist, no need to be hoity-toity or a fuddy-duddy; if the standard is whatever literary bric-a-brac makes its way by hocus-pocus into that knick-knack we calls a hobson-jobson, or dictionary, he shouldn't  dilly-dally, but cringle-crangle through that gew-gaw and look it up snip-snap. A shilly-shally through Google wouldn't hurt either; though it can go higgledy-piggledy sort of willy-nilly, we can help argy-bargy through the crinkum-crankum to find the miminy-piminy that makes us hubba-bubba.

Comment: [crisscross, dillydally, riffraff, etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80547/crisscross-dillydally-riffraff-etc/80550#80550)

Comment: also related [Why is a rhyming word beginning with “h” put before another word to create a new term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358182/why-is-a-rhyming-word-beginning-with-h-put-before-another-word-to-create-a-new)

Comment: @choster Freeze, mister!

Answer (score 4):

"New words formed by fusing together parts of existing words are known as blends. They used to be called portmanteau words..."

Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/new-word-combining-two-other-words

noun: helter-skelter; plural noun: helter-skelters

> 1. disorder; confusion.
>      "the helter-skelter of a school day"
> 2. BRITISH
>      a tall spiral slide winding around a tower at a fair.
>
> Origin
>   late 16th century (as an adverb): a rhyming jingle of unknown origin, perhaps symbolic of running feet or from Middle English *skelte* ‘hasten.’

Source: [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Ol0qWqnoK4fqUqfqmegL&q=%22helter-skelter%20definition%22&oq=%22helter-skelter%20definition%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1l4j0i8i30k1l3.33585.38613.0.39013.2.2.0.0.0.0.178.326.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.325...0i22i30k1.0.G7HOUkzd_J0)

It is a compound word, and just because Middle English *skelte* ‘hasten’ is no longer in use... It doesn't mean the compound form can't persevere.

*Helter Skelter*, without the hyphen, is the title of a book, a song by The Beatles, and a term in French as well.

Comment: Guess the OP skelted to ask his question.

Comment: No really I think I may have been oh so willfully duped. Twenty three and the like. :)